# How to integrate Authorize.Net payment in ASP.NET MVC and receive payment status?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorize.net

I have tried everything from Authorize.Net documentation, but there all info about api endpoints, did not found any info about MVC integration. I`m quite novice in api endpoints and how should it connect with mvc project.

Looking for any advise or links, how to integrate MVC with Authorize.Net. Thanks.

Comment: It took me all but 2 seconds to find this code sample Googling Authorize.net MVC.  https://github.com/Authorizenet/sample-code-csharp/tree/40526f6e763825447ff934ac03eff464bd5dad8a

Comment: @Dennis1679 thanks, I tried, but did not found info about mvc integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using an API it doesn't matter which framework (MVC, Angular, Laravel) you use to call that API. You only need a basic knowledge of your framework and which API method does what, then you're ready to go.

Anyway, Authorize has a great [sample code](https://github.com/Authorizenet/sample-code-csharp/tree/40526f6e763825447ff934ac03eff464bd5dad8a) on github, it will help you to learn how to use its API methods in your production code.

If you find it hard to understand, take a look at [Authorize API Developer Guide](https://developer.authorize.net/api/) to know what does the API do and how? It contains parts of sample project on github and will help you to understand them well.

As an example [Here](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/payment_transactions.html) is the basics of the API like:

- Basics of credit card processing
- Stages of a transaction
- Transaction types
- Transaction settings
- And so on...